# Where is syscall_sw.h in Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly

Where is the file `syscall_sw.h` in Mac OS X?

I'm using it to program the classes found within in assembly, but I can only find the file on the Internet. I want to find it on my actual operating system filesystem. I've downloaded all of XCode and installed the Components and Documentation, but I still can't find the file.

Comment: It's not public on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a public* header -- it can, however, be found in the kernel source code:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.9.2/osfmk/kern/syscall_sw.h

*: Indicating that you should not need it unless you're working in the kernel.

Comment: So, there's no way to download the headers, like in FreeBSD? I just have to constantly reference through the Internet or by a manual download?

Comment: You can download the whole XNU source tarball here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/xnu/ There's no headers-only version because this header is only used internally within the kernel.